# Calculating a cumulative sum up to a specified value in MDX

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I have mdx query:

```
select 
{[Measures].[Count] , 
[Measures].[Stock]
} on columns,
( [Product Group].[Group].&[DEKA], [Date].[Year Month].members) on rows
from [CUBENAME]
```

[image]

How to calculate the sum of several next value "count" until reaching a max value lower than "stock".
And I need to know how many rows have been added up.
The result should be as shown in the picture

[image]